# Remove Arabic Diacritic

Tags: php, arabic, diacritics

I want php to convert this...

```
Text : الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ
converted to : الحمد لله رب العالمين
```

I am not sure where to start and how to do it. Absolutely no idea. I have done some research, found this link http://www.suhailkaleem.com/2009/08/26/remove-diacritics-from-arabic-text-quran/ but it is not using php. I would like to use php and covert the above text to converted text. I want to remove any diacritic from user input arabic text

Comment: Why no idea? `strtr()` or `str_replace()` will work just fine. So replacements would be `['نَ'<='ن']` for instance. It's just different symbols (with diacritic and without) - so that's it.

Comment: Following perl regex does it for me: `$str = NFD($str) =~ s/[\p{Mn}]//rg;`. Shouldn't be too hard turning it into php.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The vowel diacritics in Arabic are [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), meaning that a simple search for these should suffice. There's no need to have a replace rule for every possible consonant with every possible vowel, which is a little tedious.

Here's a working example that outputs what you need:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8', true);
$string = 'الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ';

$remove = array('ِ', 'ُ', 'ٓ', 'ٰ', 'ْ', 'ٌ', 'ٍ', 'ً', 'ّ', 'َ');
$string = str_replace($remove, '', $string);

echo $string; // outputs الحمد لله رب العالمين
```

What's important here is the `$remove` array. It looks weird because there's a combining character between the `'` quotes, so it modifies one of those single quotes. This might need saving in the same character encoding as your text is.

Comment: @SyedSajid Glad to hear it! Take care

Comment: For typing diacritics in Arabic keyboards u can use this Asci codes(those codes are Asci not Unicode) in windows editors typing diacritics directly or holding Alt + (type the code of diacritic character) This is the codes

ـَ(0243) ـِ(0246) ـُ(0245) ـً(0240) ـٍ(0242) ـٌ(0241) ـْ(0250) ـّ(0248) ـ ـ(0220)

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
$string = 'الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ';
$string = preg_replace("~[\x{064B}-\x{065B}]~u", "", $string);
echo $string; // outputs الحمد لله رب العالمين
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code, it's works fine:**

```
<?php    
$str = 'الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ';

$unicode = [
            "~[\x{0600}-\x{061F}]~u",   
            "~[\x{063B}-\x{063F}]~u",   
            "~[\x{064B}-\x{065E}]~u",   
            "~[\x{066A}-\x{06FF}]~u",   
        ];

$str = preg_replace($unicode, "", $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

See: [Arabic unicode](https://graphemica.com/blocks/arabic)

Thank's for: [Hosein Shahrestani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50089811/2269902)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not Arabic speaking, but i think you can make some alphabet remap:

```
function remap($string) {
    $remap = [
        'ą' => 'a',
        'č' => 'c',
        /* ... Arabic alphabet remap */
    ];
    return str_replace(array_keys($remap), $remap, $string);
}

echo remap('ąčasdadfg'); // => acasdadfg
```

Comment: A quick look shows that Arabic got 80 Diacritics and 26 Letters. Too many combinations to make a simple str_replace viable.

Comment: Arabic has 28 basic letters not 26.