# How to remove TASHKEEL / HARAKAT from given Arabic string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.2

I want to remove the following  TASHKEEL / HARAKAT from any given Arabic string without removing letters

How can i do that?

C# .net 4.6.2

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Arabic Diacritic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562974/remove-arabic-diacritic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example string taken from other question,

```
string str = "الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ";

// to be replaced characters
char[] tashkeel = new char[]{'ِ', 'ُ', 'ٓ', 'ٰ', 'ْ', 'ٌ', 'ٍ', 'ً', 'ّ', 'َ'};

// doing the replacement
foreach(char c in tashkeel)
    str = str.Replace(c.ToString(),"");

MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
      str= str.Replace("\u064b", "");
        str= str.Replace("\u064f", "");
        str= str.Replace("\u064c", "");
        str= str.Replace("\u0652", "");
        str= str.Replace("\u064d", "");
        str= str.Replace("\u0650", "");
        str= str.Replace("\u0651", "");
        str= str.Replace("\u064e", "");
```