# Using RegEx to highlight Arabic text

Tags: php, regex

My database contains Arabic text with diacritics/tashkeel. To search user types without diacritics/tashkeel and I can successfully search using full-text search statements but unable to highlight the search term using regular expressions:

```php
$str="اِنَّ الَّذِیۡنَ اٰمَنُوۡا وَ عَمِلُوا الصّٰلِحٰتِ وَ اَخۡبَتُوۡۤا اِلٰی رَبِّہِمۡ ۙ اُولٰٓئِکَ اَصۡحٰبُ الۡجَنَّۃِ ۚ ہُمۡ فِیۡہَا خٰلِدُوۡنَ";

$ptr="عملوا";

$result = preg_replace("/$ptr/", '<span style="background:yellow">' . $ptr . '</span>', $str);

echo $result;
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I can't read Arabic but clearly the search pattern in `$ptr` isn't in `$str`. `عَمِلُوا` and `عملوا` are two completely different strings programmatically speaking.

Comment: Is this a simple matter of writing the missing unicode flag on the expression?  https://3v4l.org/jHv59  Run that demo and click on the eye icon on the right in the output area to see that the found string is correctly highlighted (once you actually have a match between the needle and the haystack).   ...to answer my own question, no, the unicode flag is not needed if the needle _actually_ exists in `$str`. https://3v4l.org/lfRDp  This is not a good [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string has extra character like `tashkil`. but character you want to match have no `tashkil` so solution is replace extra char and make both strings similar.

```
<?php
function stripDiacritics($str) {
    $diacritic = array("ِ" ,"ٰ" ,"ّ" ,"ۡ" ,"ٖ" ,"ٗ" ,"ؘ" ,"ؙ" ,"ؚ" ,"ٍ" ,"َ" ,"ُ", "ٓ" ,"ْ" , "ٌ" , "ٍ",  "ً",  "ّ", "ۤ");
    $str = str_replace($diacritic, '', $str); 
    return $str;       
}

$str="اِنَّ الَّذِیۡنَ اٰمَنُوۡا وَ عَمِلُوا الصّٰلِحٰتِ وَ اَخۡبَتُوۡۤا اِلٰی رَبِّہِمۡ ۙ اُولٰٓئِکَ اَصۡحٰبُ الۡجَنَّۃِ ۚ ہُمۡ فِیۡہَا خٰلِدُوۡنَ";
$words = explode(" ",$str);
$resultText='';
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $strippedWord = stripDiacritics($word);
    $ptr="عملوا";
    if ($strippedWord == $ptr) {
        $resultText .= ' <span style="background:yellow">'.$word.'</span>';
    }            
    else {
        $resultText .= ' '.$word;
    }
}
echo $resultText;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

While @Artier's answer might work acceptably, it's not the greatest idea to have loose UTF-8 combining marks in the source code and, from the bit I've gleaned from Google, they may not be covering the entire range of Arabic diacritics/combining marks.

Disclaimer: I know *very* little about Arabic, but I *am* very fussy about UTF-8.

@Artier's answer seems to have been culled from the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562974/remove-arabic-diacritic), but the accepted answer is frequently not the optimal solution. One of these other two options from the same set of answers is likely closer to being canonically correct.

```php
function strip_arabic_diacritics_1($str) {
    return preg_replace("~[\x{064B}-\x{065B}]~u", "", $str);
}

function strip_arabic_diacritics_2($str) {
    $ranges = [
        "~[\x{0600}-\x{061F}]~u",   
        "~[\x{063B}-\x{063F}]~u",   
        "~[\x{064B}-\x{065E}]~u",   
        "~[\x{066A}-\x{06FF}]~u",   
    ];

    return preg_replace($ranges, "", $str);
}

$str="اِنَّ الَّذِیۡنَ اٰمَنُوۡا وَ عَمِلُوا الصّٰلِحٰتِ وَ اَخۡبَتُوۡۤا اِلٰی رَبِّہِمۡ ۙ اُولٰٓئِکَ اَصۡحٰبُ الۡجَنَّۃِ ۚ ہُمۡ فِیۡہَا خٰلِدُوۡنَ";

$ptr="عملوا";

var_dump(
    $str,
    strip_arabic_diacritics_1($str),
    strip_arabic_diacritics_2($str)
);
```

Output:

```
string(265) "اِنَّ الَّذِیۡنَ اٰمَنُوۡا وَ عَمِلُوا الصّٰلِحٰتِ وَ اَخۡبَتُوۡۤا اِلٰی رَبِّہِمۡ ۙ اُولٰٓئِکَ اَصۡحٰبُ الۡجَنَّۃِ ۚ ہُمۡ فِیۡہَا خٰلِدُوۡنَ"
string(183) "ان الذیۡن اٰمنوۡا و عملوا الصٰلحٰت و اخۡبتوۡۤا الٰی ربہمۡ ۙ اولٰئک اصۡحٰب الۡجنۃ ۚ ہمۡ فیۡہا خٰلدوۡن"
string(127) "ان الذن امنوا و عملوا الصلحت و اخبتوا ال ربم  اولئ اصحب الجن  م فا خلدون"
```

As well, relying on `explode()` for word splitting is generally not feasible for human-written text as it will not respect punctuation or other non-space word breaks. This is the exact use case for [`IntlBreakIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlbreakiterator.php):

```php
function strip_arabic_diacritics($str) {
    return strip_arabic_diacritics_2($str);
}

$br = IntlBreakIterator::createWordInstance();
$br->setText($str);

$output = '';
$ptr_stripped = strip_arabic_diacritics($ptr);

foreach($br->getPartsIterator() as $word) {
    $word_stripped = strip_arabic_diacritics($word);
    if( $ptr_stripped == $word_stripped ) {
        $output .= sprintf('<span class="...">%s</span>', $word);
    } else {
        $output .= $word;
    }
}

var_dump( $output );
```

Output:

```
string(290) "اِنَّ الَّذِیۡنَ اٰمَنُوۡا وَ <span class="...">عَمِلُوا</span> الصّٰلِحٰتِ وَ اَخۡبَتُوۡۤا اِلٰی رَبِّہِمۡ ۙ اُولٰٓئِکَ اَصۡحٰبُ الۡجَنَّۃِ ۚ ہُمۡ فِیۡہَا خٰلِدُوۡنَ"
```

The source string looks a bit wonky because of the switches between RTL and LTR, but it should render properly.

Comment: hey `ان الذن امنوا و عملوا الصلحت و اخبتوا ال ربم  اولئ اصحب الجن  م فا خلدون ` its completely different generated text.  strip_arabic_diacritics_2 is not create correct text. its not skipping diacritics its skipping characters.

Comment: Finally found [a decent table of the Arabic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)) and wow, yeah `fn_2()` covers a _lot_ of stuff that doesn't look like diacritics. 066A-06FF? That's 2/3rds of the plane! If you want to suggest a sane set of ranges I'd be happy to amend my answer to reflect that.

Comment: [Even better breakdown straight from the unicode consortium.](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) It looks like 064B-065F covers the combining marks in the plane, and then 06D6-06ED seem to be combining marks as well, but are primarily used for Quranic annotation. More annotations... honorifics, subtending marks, _super_tending marks... I am so lost.

Comment: one is skip Tashkil, and one more thing I am unable to find

Comment: skip these characters `"\u0650" ,"\u0670" ,"\u0651" ,"\u06E1" ,"\u0656" ,"\u0657" ,"\u0618" ,"\u0619" ,"\u061A" ,"\u064D" ,"\u064E" ,"\u064F", "\u0653" ,"\u0652" , "\u064c" , "\u064d",  "\u064b",  "\u0651"`